# how to receive array using retrofitAPI

Tags: java, android

i want receive the array data in Android

[image: ```]

```
profileAPI.getBadge().enqueue(new Callback<SingleResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<SingleResult> call, Response<SingleResult> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
            SingleResult data = response.body();

            //here
        }
    }
}
```

I need data from badges 1 to 6.
Values in one boolean object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create data class Badge

```
data class Badge
(
   val bagdeId: Int,
   val badge1 : Boolean, 
  val badge2 : Boolean, 
  val badge3 : Boolean, 
  val badge4 : Boolean, 
  val badge5 : Boolean, 
  val badge6 : Boolean, 
)
```

Use in Call, Callback, Response, replace SingleResult

```
Call<List<Badge>>
Callback<List<Badge>>
Response<List<Badge>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create model class Badge

```
@SerializedName("msg")
@Expose
private String message;

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Datas> data = null;

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public List<Datas> getData() {
    return data;
}
```

And then create a model class Datas

```
@SerializedName("badgeId")
@Expose
private int badgeId;

@SerializedName("badge1")
@Expose
private boolean badge1;

@SerializedName("badge2")
@Expose
private boolean badge2;

@SerializedName("badge3")
@Expose
private boolean badge3;

@SerializedName("badge4")
@Expose
private boolean badge4;

@SerializedName("badge5")
@Expose
private boolean badge5;

@SerializedName("badge6")
@Expose
private boolean badge6;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Datas{" +
            "badgeId=" + badgeId +
            ", badge1=" + badge1 +
            ", badge2=" + badge2 +
            ", badge3=" + badge3 +
            ", badge4=" + badge4 +
            ", badge5=" + badge5 +
            ", badge6=" + badge6 +
            '}';
}
```

Your get request will be like this

```
@GET("v3/bc3a5fef-3105-4499-961e-fb103b706220")
Call<Badge> getResponse();
```

And your code:

```
    profileAPI.getResponse().enqueue(new Callback<Badge>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Badge> call, Response<Badge> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                Badge data = response.body();
                System.out.println("response:" + data.getData().toString());
            }
        }
```